# Large gap between the grabbed game object and controller

Tags: unity, controllers, collider

When i grab a gameobject, there is a gap between them. I have tried changing the scale of the colliders, tool handle position from global to pivot but nothing worked for me. Should i reset the pivot points of model in 3D modeller and reimport it again or is there another way to solve this?

I have attached few screenshot related to the problem [image: Gap between controller and game object]]
[image: Controller Box Collider Settings]
[image: GameObject inspector]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i am using VRTK toolkit. So, i changed the grab attach mechanism from child of controllers to fixed joint and selected precision grab. This solved my problem.